# Remove default cell padding from HTML nested tables

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a parent table and each td tag in tr tag contains a child table (For example - Data WS-C3.... in the picture).

```
[![<table class="table table--bordered table--nostripes table-top">
    <thead>
       <th>PID</th>
       <th>Base Licence</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
               <a (click)="addNewPid()">Add New PID</a>
           </td>
           <td><a (click)="addNewPid()">Add New PID</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <custom-table here ></custom-table>
           </td>
           <td>
               <custom-table here></custom-table>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>]
```

Since there are less elements in the right column, it's adding default padding to match the size of left column. I want to display those 3 rows of the right column right after Add new PID. How to remove the default padding present in the right column? I tried givng span=0 but its not working. Any idea please

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OUz3.png

Comment: I very much doubt that this is an actual padding to begin with … more likely a simple issue of vertical-alignment. Provide a proper [mcve] please, if you need more help figuring this out.

Comment: @CBroe Is this default span behavior of tables can be overridden? Or we cannot?

Comment: Go read up on the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: @CBroe I dont want inside content of the table to top; I'm trying to bring that whole inner table of right column to below the Add Nwew PID row

Comment: First comment, last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
tr td {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```